# How can I fix the Spotlight index for an encfs-mounted directory?

Tags: macos, spotlight, filesystem

Until recently, on OS X 10.8, I was using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) (which in turn uses Spotlight) to search files and directories on an [encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs)-mounted partition (which is mounted off a folder in my Dropbox directory).

I used to use the command `sudo mdutil -i on ~/Dropbox-encfs` to enable indexing for that partition once it had been mounted (typically, I remounted every time I rebooted).

However, since upgrading to OS X 10.9, entering the same command returns the error `Error: unknown indexing state`. Indexing and searching on my main root partition continues to work:

```
~$ sudo mdutil -a -s
/:
    Indexing enabled.
/Users/myuserdirectory/Dropbox-encfs:
    Error: unknown indexing state.
```

Has something changed in OS X 10.9 that might cause this? How would I go about debugging or fixing this problem?

I'm using encfs version 1.7.4p1. I've already tried turning on and off the indexing (`-i on`, `-i off`), and using the `-E` flag to mdutil to erase the store.

I mount the encfs partition using the following command:

`sudo encfs --public -ovolname=Dropbox-encfs ~/Dropbox/.encfs-crypted ~/Dropbox-encfs`

Aside from the indexing problem, the mounted encfs partition otherwise seems to work fine.

I should add that I am also seeing warnings of this form in `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Dec 23 14:51:20 montpelier.local mds[57]: (Warning) Volume:
vsd:0x7ffe0c826c00 Open failed.  failureCount:7
```

Comment: I'm on 10.9.1 and can get the status to show "Indexing enabled" for the encfs volume when appending the option `-o local`. Nevertheless, files from inside the volume still do not appear for me in searched for some reason.

Comment: @GJ, perfect, that worked for me - and I do get the search results. Thanks. Not sure why it doesn't work for you - perhaps indexing hasn't yet finished? I monitored it with the Spotlight icon in the top-right. If you turn this into an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Let me be more precise: I can search inside the encrypted volume when initiating the search in a Finder window that is currently viewing the volume, and switching the search scope at the top of the results from "This Mac" to just "Dropbox-encfs", which means the Spotlight index is probably fine. My problem is that I can't get combined results across both the entire regular disk and the encrypted volume. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @GJ, hmm, well I don't do my searches that way - I use Alfred to initiate my search, as I mentioned in my Q. I just tried it in Finder, and the results do seem to be separated. I think that may be by design, though.

Comment: Andrew, do you also get the dropbox to get stuck on the "syncing" mode due to the spotlight folder having permission problems? Or did you manage to work around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending the option `-o local` to the `mount` (i.e. `encfs`) command seems to work...